# Can't see site externally

Tags: apache, xampp, osticket

I'm brand spanking new to setting up websites, so go easy.

Basically I setup an osticket system on my XAMPP stack and It works locally no problem but when I try to access it from my public IP it won't connect.

I've port forwarded port 12345 -> 80 as my server listens on 80.
So theoretically if I type  in my URL bar it should connect right?

In the `httpd.conf` file for Apache do I enter the external or internal IP address? I'm assuming I leave it as localhost because the `.conf` file is local to the server.

---

My networking setup:

Firewall setup:
`<PublicIP:12345> ALLOW <PriavteIP>`

Port forwarding setup:
`<PublicIP:12345> -> <PrivateIP:80>`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without understanding more about your setup. I'm going to assume you have a router that connects your internal network to the Internet, and you have one or more computers connected in your network, and your server is one of those.

So are you talking about the port forwarding rules on your public-facing router's firewall? If you are forwarding port 12345 from your router to port 80 on your server, the reason it won't work is because a standard HTTP request from a public machine will come to your router on port 80, not port 12345. Are you entering in a URL with the 12345 port number in it? If anything, you should simply be routing all requests to port 80 on your router to the IP of your server.

You can check this if you try to view your web site using the port number in the URL. So if your IP address to your router is 5.6.7.8 you would enter http://5.6.7.8:12345 and this would load your web page, as the request for a page from port 12345 would get forwarded to port 80 on your server. But honestly I think you just need to get rid of port 12345.

Comment: Yeah I was typing `5.6.7.8:12345/osticket` in the URL bar. I have absolutely no clue what's going.

Comment: What does your httpd.conf file look like? I don't use any IP address in my .conf files, instead the virtualhost directive looks like this:

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>` which means any request to your webserver will serve the web site you describe in your virtualhost section. Consider restoring your httpd.conf to the original and using virtualhost .conf files instead.

Comment: Also check your error.log and access.log files to see if there's anything in there that might give you a hint.